# How to deploy October CMS as a child site of main site

Tags: octobercms

everyone
I have some problem with deploy octobercms with Nginx
This is the the main site url:https://staging.guardianangel.network
And I want to deploy my october cms site as a subdomain of this main site
i.e https://staging.guardianangel.network/advice

This is what I did but it doesn't work correctly

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/staging.guardianangel.network/before/*;
​
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name staging.guardianangel.network;
​
    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/staging.guardianangel.network/485559/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/staging.guardianangel.network/485559/server.key;
​
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;
​
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
​
    charset utf-8;
​
    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/staging.guardianangel.network/server/*;
​
​
    root /home/forge/staging.guardianangel.network/current/public;
​
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
​
    error_page 404 /index.php;
​
    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/guardianangel.network-error.log error;
​
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
​
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
​
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
​
        auth_basic            "Restricted Area";
        auth_basic_user_file  /home/forge/staging.guardianangel.network/.htpasswd;
    }
​
    location /advice {
        root /home/forge/advice/public;
​
        rewrite ^/advice/(.*)$ /$1 break;
​
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
​
    location ~ \.php$ {
        set $newurl $request_uri;
​
        if ($newurl ~ ^/advice(.*)$) {
            set $newurl $1;
            root /home/forge/advice/public;
        }
​
        #return 200 $args; add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        #return 200 $uri; add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        #return 200 $document_root; add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        #return 200 $request_uri; add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        #return 200 $newurl; add_header Content-Type text/plain;
​
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $newurl;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
​
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
​
    location /resources {
        alias /home/forge/blog/current/public;
​
        try_files $uri $uri/ @resources;
​
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
​
    location @resources {
        rewrite ^/resources/(.*) /resources/index.php?$query_string;
    }
​
    client_max_body_size 12M;
}
​
# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/staging.guardianangel.network/after/*;
```

When I visit https://staging.guardianangel.network/advice all styling is broken down and when I want to try go to backend (https://staging.guardianangel.network/advice/backend) it redirects me to https://staging.guardianangel.network/backend/backend/auth

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
RewriteBase /advice/
```

to your `.htaccess` file.

Reference: https://octobercms.com/docs/setup/configuration